# how to import colors in variables.scss

Tags: css, angular, sass, ionic2, ionic3

ionic2/3 : how to import colors in variables.scss. I have a scss file with some colors; how I can import and use them in variables.scss in ionic angular?

```
$colors: (
  carscolor:  #C5281C,
  primary:    #387ef5,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #000,
  popover:    #404040,
  unread:       #808080,
  note:         #666,
  );
```

Comment: Why don’t write the colors directly to variables.scss?

Comment: He might be using in `each` loop. How to extract single color from this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call your `_extra.scss` file and import it like this in the beginning of `variables.scss`:

```
@import 'extra';
```